# SQL query performance statistics messages returned multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I am running this query 1 on SQL Server management studio and see it returns me like 3 messages, but same when inside stored procedure has nearly 10 - 20 messages from Statistics. Whats happening and why do i see them ?

```
SET STATISTICS IO,TIME ON;
GO
    SELECT [UserId]
         ,[UserType]
         ,[CreateDT]
         ,[EffectiveDT]
       FROM [dbo].[People] ORDER BY [UserId]
SET STATISTICS IO,TIME OFF;
GO
```

Messages i receive are below

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'People'. Scan count 1, logical reads 155, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 143 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 143 ms.
```

Is the total elapsed time for the query 143ms + 143ms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below

```
set statistics time on
select * from test
set statistics time off
```

**output:**

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 264 ms..
```

Now add print statement   and some variable

```
set statistics time on

print' statistics time '
declare @a int
set @a =1

select * from test
set statistics time off
```

**output:**

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(59 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 264 ms.
```

In above piece of code  total execution time is 1+1+264.

hope this helps on how it works

Comment: Does this mean the total time taken to execute the query in your case is `1 + 1 + 264` ?