# Elapsed time and CPU time are incorrect when run from external application

Tags: sql-server, console-application, sqlperformance

Is there any improvements or magical way when a `SqlCommand` is executed from a .net console application ?
I see huge improvements and consistent times when running the command from .net based application but its completely different when executed in Sql server management studio.

.NET Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {

                string strConn = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=school;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn)) 
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = "SET NOCOUNT OFF;SET STATISTICS IO,TIME ON; Exec spStudents @type='SELECTALL';SET STATISTICS IO,TIME OFF;";
                    conn.InfoMessage += conn_InfoMessage;
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                //grab the first column to force the row down the pipe
                                var x = reader[0];
                            }
                        } while (reader.NextResult());

                    }
                    Console.Read();
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }

        static void conn_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (SqlError item in e.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Message);
            }
        }
```

I see sql reports consistent times of `CPU time = 130 ~ 150 ms` and `elapsed time = 250ms ~ 300 ms`. But when running same in SSMS it reports me `CPU time = 900ms, elapsed time = 1s`. So which one is reliable result ?
another related question that i asked yesterday [SQL query performance statistics messages returned multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913106/sql-query-performance-statistics-messages-returned-multiple-times)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers thanks for responding. sql engine reports to the c# application that cpu takes times in range of `130 - 150 ms` and elapsed time as `250ms - 300ms`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers added related question i asked yesterday. That has the complete message returned by sql engine. Perhaps it will help ?

Comment: Just a guess but using the `sqlcommand`, you are executing the procedure and stop the statistics before looping over the results. Using SSMS, I would assume that all or at least part of returning the results is included in the timings you see.

Comment: If that's happening i should have been getting longer times in C# application but then its the opposite, SSMS reports higher execution time

Comment: No, it's the other way around?! The premise is that SSMS is including streaming the results in it's statistics while you by using the sqlcommand are not.

Comment: Ooh so does the SQL engine know what application we use, i mean how does it know i use `sqlcommand` and it does not show me elapsed time in the statistics. Man more i dig into sql , more bigger it gets to be... :)

Comment: that's what *I think* is happening but I have *nothing* to back it up so I would welcome a definitive answer as much as you.